# Run an Ansible handler only once for the entire playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

I would like to run a handler only once in an entire playbook.

I attempted using an include statement in the following in the playbook file, but this resulted in the handler being run multiple times, once for each play:

```
- name: Configure common config
  hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
        OE: "{{ ansible_hostname[5] }}"
  roles:
    - { role: common }
  handlers:
    - include: handlers/main.yml

- name: Configure metadata config
  hosts: metadata
  become: true
  vars:
        OE: "{{ ansible_hostname[5] }}"
  roles:
    - { role: metadata }
  handlers:
    - include: handlers/main.yml
```

Here is the content of handlers/main.yml:

```
- name: restart autofs
  service:
    name: autofs.service
    state: restarted
```

Here is an example of one of the tasks that notifies the handler:

```
- name: Configure automount - /opt/local/xxx in /etc/auto.direct
  lineinfile:
     dest: /etc/auto.direct
     regexp: "^/opt/local/xxx"
     line: "/opt/local/xxx   -acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0,rdirplus,rw,hard,intr,bg,retry=2  nfs_server:/vol/xxx"
  notify: restart autofs
```

How can I get the playbook to only execute the handler once for the entire playbook?

Comment: Your playbook looks a bit wild. What is the general idea of this playbook and why do you include the handler here? A handler should be notified by a task, so it is a part of the role. 

Have a look at the docs how to use a handler: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html.

Another way to run a specific task only once is the following: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once

Comment: Not sure what is meant by wild. The playbook is a series of plays, of which there are two in the example. I want to use a single handler for multiple plays, and have it execute once for the entire playbook. I hope that makes sense. Don't need to run a task only once, need to run a handler only once.

Comment: @techraf There are multiple tasks in the plays that notify the handler. I edited the question and added one of the tasks.

Comment: @user3155618 I think you might want to check my [new suggested way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673434/2947502) for achieving this. It is simpler than previous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The answer**

The literal answer to the question in the title is: no.

Playbook is a list of plays. Playbook has no namespace, no variables, no state. All the configuration, logic, and tasks are defined in plays.

Handler is a task with a different calling schedule (not sequential, but conditional, once at the end of a play, or triggered by the `meta: flush_handlers` task).

A handler belongs to a play, not a playbook, and there is no way to trigger it outside of the play (i.e. at the end of the playbook).

---

**Solution**

The solution to the problem is possible without referring to handlers.

You can use [`group_by` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/group_by_module.html) to create an ad-hoc group based on the result of the tasks at the bottom of each play.

Then you can define a separate play at the end of the playbook restarting the service on targets belonging to the above ad-hoc group.

Refer to the below stub for the idea:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    # roles declaration
  tasks:
    - # an example task modifying Nginx configuration
      register: nginx_configuration

    # ... other tasks ...

    - name: the last task in the play
      group_by:
        key: hosts_to_restart_{{ 'nginx' if nginx_configuration is changed else '' }}

# ... other plays ...

- hosts: hosts_to_restart_nginx
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - service:
        name: nginx
        state: restarted
```

Answer (score 2):

### Possible solution

Use handlers to add hosts to in-memory inventory. Then add `play` to run restart service only for these hosts.
See this example:

If task is changed, it notify `mark to restart` to set fact, that host needs service restart.

Second handler `add host` is quite special, because `add_host` task only run once for whole play even in handler, see also [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html). But if notified, it will run after marking is done implied from handlers order.
Handler loops over hosts on which tasks were run and check if host service needs restart, if yes, add to special `hosts_to_restart` group.

Because facts are persistent across plays, notify third handler `clear mark` for affected hosts.

A lot of lines you hide with moving handlers to separate file and include them.

inventory file

```
10.1.1.[1:10]
[primary]
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.5
```

test.yml

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: Random change to notify trigger
        debug: msg="test"
        changed_when: "1|random == 1"
        notify:
            - mark to restart
            - add host
            - clear mark
  handlers:
      - name: mark to restart
        set_fact: restart_service=true
      - name: add host
        add_host:
            name: "{{item}}"
            groups: "hosts_to_restart"
        when: hostvars[item].restart_service is defined and hostvars[item].restart_service
        with_items: "{{ansible_play_batch}}"
      - name: clear mark
        set_fact: restart_service=false

- hosts: primary
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: Change to notify trigger
        debug: msg="test"
        changed_when: true
        notify:
            - mark to restart
            - add host
            - clear mark
  handlers:
      - name: mark to restart
        set_fact: restart_service=true
      - name: add host
        add_host:
            name: "{{item}}"
            groups: "hosts_to_restart"
        when: hostvars[item].restart_service is defined and hostvars[item].restart_service
        with_items: "{{ansible_play_batch}}"
      - name: clear mark
        set_fact: restart_service=false


- hosts: hosts_to_restart
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: Restart service
        debug: msg="Service restarted"
        changed_when: true
```

Comment: I think you might want to check my [new suggested way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673434/2947502), as fixing on the old one gets pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

A handler triggered in `post_tasks` will run after everything else.  And the handler can be set to `run_once: true`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your handler should do. Anyway, as for [official documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change), handlers

> are triggered at the end of each block of tasks in a play,
>   and will **only be triggered once even if notified by multiple different
>   tasks** [...] As of Ansible 2.2, handlers can also “listen” to generic topics, and tasks can notify those topics as follows:

So handlers are notified / executed once for each block of tasks.
May be you get your goal just keeping handlers after "all" target hosts, but it doesn't seem a clean use of handlers.
.

Comment: If the handler is included only in the play for "all" target hosts, then it will not get run when notified in the other plays.

Comment: You are right. But what your "handlers/main.yml" is doing?

Comment: Edited the original question, please see the content of "handlers/main.yml" in the post.